# Python adding reverse map dictionary attribute in a class inherited from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python and was trying to create a class inherit from dictionary and at the same time having an attribute name reversemap. The reversemap attribute is another dictionary which contains key of a value from the main dictionary. Example as below:-

```
class DictWithReverseMap(dict):
  def __init__(self):
    self.reversemap = dict()
    self.__dict__ = dict()
  def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    self.__dict__[key] = item
    self.reversemap[item] = key

hh= DictWithReverseMap()
hh['1'] = "a"
hh['2'] = "a"
hh['3'] = "b"

print hh[1]  #result [a]
print hh.reversemap[b]    #result [3]
```

When I try to assign a to hh['1'] it will throw out error stating that 
self.reversemap[item] = key
AttributeError: 'DictWithReverseMap' object has no attribute 'reversemap'

Any Idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use the functions in the superclass (`dict`). It is how you should implement it

```
class DictWithReverseMap(dict):
  def __init__(self):
    super(DictWithReverseMap, self).__init__()
    self.reversemap = dict()
  def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    super(DictWithReverseMap, self).__setitem__(key, item)
    self.reversemap[item] = key

hh= DictWithReverseMap()
hh['1'] = "a"
hh['2'] = "a"
hh['3'] = "b"

print hh.keys()
print hh['1']  # Remember to use quote around the number 1
print hh.reversemap['b']    # Remember to use quote around the letter b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! One more question why print hh.reversemap['a'] only return 2. It should return both 1 and 2 right?

Comment: A key cannot have 2 values in a dict.  But you could change your approach to use a list instead.